# Is it possible to convert/export my 3D model (dae/blend/3ds/...) into GLSL ES 2.0?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, 3d, glsl, blender

Is it possible to export or convert my 3D models into GLSL ES 2.0? Is there any converter or any exporter tool/addon existing for any editor programs like Blender/3DS MAX/Maya that creates GLSL ES 2.0 code?

I'd like to create my models conveniently in any of the above mentioned editors and then I'd like to export/convert them into GLSL ES 2.0.

I already have a template WebGL code that displays my shaders. I want to replace my fragment shader and vertex shader parts with the GLSL ES code created automatically by a converter or an exporter tool.

I'd like to do something like this (but for GLSL ES 2.0):
[Blender to GLSL](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?233186-Export-Materials-to-GLSL-Code)

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to accomplish? I am aware of exporters that generate code but in general models are transformed into data formats that fit the purposes of program and then loaded.

Comment: I just refreshed my original question. Please see the newly added last rows.

Comment: The edited lines still don't make sense. Using OBJ files as an example: A model is made up of vertices with the following information - position, normals, texture coordinates. These vertices then need to be sent to the GPU with OpenGL ES calls for further processing. Then, the GLSL shader performs several parallel calculations on all the loaded vertices to compute a position (gl_Position) and color (gl_FragColor). In summary, OpenGL ES sends your model data to the GPU and GLSL performs operations on that data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing apples with cars here. OpenGL is a drawing API, GLSL is a programming language for implementing shader code.

3D models are neither of that. The sole question "how can I convert my 3D model to OpanGL?" makes no sense.

> Is it possible?

No. Because that's not the purpose of GLSL

Choose a model file format (preferrably implementing a reading parser is straightforward for) implement the parser, fill in apropriate data structures and feed those into the right parts of OpenGL, making the right calls to draw them.

OpenGL itself doesn't deal with models, scenes or even files. GLSL is not even a file format, it's a language.

---

I'd start with OBJ or STL files. They're reasonably easy to read and interpret and match very closely the primitive types OpenGL uses.

Probably the hardest format to read is .blend files; effectively a .blend file is a dump of the Blender process memory image. It takes a fully featured Blender (or something very similar to it) to make sense of a .blend file.

---

---

#### Update due to comment:

Please, please carefully read what this exporter script you linked to does: It takes an objects *material settings* (not the model itself) and generates GLSL code, that when used in the right framework (i.e. apropriate uniform and attribute names, matrix setup, etc.) will result in shading operations that resemble those material settings as close as possible. **The script does not export a model!**

You asked about exporting a 3D model. That would be the mesh of the model and it's attributes to place it in the world. Materials are not what's stored in a OBJ or STL file. They're textures, and yes, shaders. But they're completely independent of the model data itself. It's perfectly possible to use the same material settings on multiple models, or to freely exchange a model's material (textures and shaders), as long as the model provides all the required vertex attributes to make this material work.

---

---

#### Update 2 due to comment:

Do you even understand what a shader does? If not, here's a short synopsis: You have vertex attribute data (in buffers). These indexed attributes are submitted to OpenGL. Using a call to glDrawElements or glDrawArrays the attributes are interpreted as primitives (points, lines or triangles (or quads on older OpenGL versions)). Each primitive is then subjected to a number of transformations.

*Mandatory:* First step is the vertex shader which responsibility is to determine its final position in the viewport.

*Optional:* After vertex shading vertices the primitives formed by the vertices undergo tesselation shading. Tesselation is used to refine geometry, for example adding detail to terrain or making curved surfaces smoother.

*Optional:* Next comes geometry shading which can replace a single vertex with a (small) number of vertices. A geometry shader may even change the primitive type. So a single point could be replaced with a triangle for example (usefull for rendering particle systems).

*Mandatory:* The last step is fragment shading the primitive. After a primitive's position in the viewport has been determined, each of the pixels it covers is processed in one or more fragments. The fragment shader is a program that determines the final color and translucency in the target framebuffer.

Each shading step is controlled by a user defined program. It is these programs, shaders they are called, that are written in GLSL. Not geometry, no models. *Programs!* And very simple programs at that. They don't produce geometry from nothing, they always process already existing geometry passed to OpenGL.

Shaders are not used for defining or storing models. They just modify them at rendering time.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't detailed enough. I updated my original question. Please take a look at it. OBJ and STL files: thank you for the tip!

Comment: @datenwolf very well explained on both accounts, the model/file side and the GLSL/OpenGL ES side too.

Comment: Please take a look at this website: iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy It's seem to me that this website has a basic WebGL engine and the user can change the displayed scene by changing the shader code only without changing any other parts of the code. I'd like to do something similar. My question in other words: I want to display a simple cube on the screen. If I have a basic OpenGL/WebGL template file (with vertex and fragment shader parts as well of course) which displays a triangle, am I able to draw a simple cube by changing the vertex and fragment shader parts ONLY?

Comment: @Fract: The shaders you see on this WebGL toy do not contain geometry. What they is, they take the geometry supplied through the usual means (vertex arrays, in buffer objects) and modify them. **A shader does not contain a model!** Plase, no discussion about this. That's not what a shader does. If you want to load a model in a WebGL setting, export it into a JSON format and load that. But please understand that **a shader does not define a model!** You can not make a cube from a triangle with just shaders.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to create a model by GLSL only and I'm unable to create a cube with just shaders. I see now! Thank you very much for the detailed answers! I think my question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.inka3d.com which converts your Maya shaders to GLSL. For the models do you need WebGL or OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: The link seems to be broken now.